# Can I run Appium for mobile with no target app?

Tags: android, ios, automation, appium

Since I'm working in a platform which works with many apps (rather than a single target app), I find the selection of a target app inefficient for my needs. I wondered if I could do something to avoid it.

I'd like to run freely, sending UI commands to iOS and Android real devices, including installing an app from another app (like Play Store, Apple Store, Test Flight, etc.)

Thanks for the help,

David.

Answer (score 2):

**The rule is: 1 Webdriver instance per application.**

You can run Appium's server with no `--app` argument by making sure auto-launch is set to false, and not setting bundleId or app.

Then, in your client/test framework, you use several webdrivers, configured to use different desired capabilities, to tie it all together under a single test case/suite.

The solution:

- You may have a test suite that sets desired_capabilities to launch the Safari app, then you install the app, then you quit the webdriver.
- Then you change the desired_capabilities to point to the bundle_id of the new app, launch another webdriver instance, do your tests, quit the webdriver..
- Then you change the desired_capabilities to point to (etc., etc.)

  ```
  driver = webdriver.new(url, desired_capabilities)
  // do some stuff
  driver.quit()

  desired_capabilities['app'] = 'company.app.com'
  driver = webdriver.new(url, desired_capabilities)
  // do some stuff
  driver.quit()

  desired_capabilities['app'] = '/path/to/application.app'
  driver = webdriver.new(url, desired_capabilities)
  // do some stuff
  driver.quit()
  ```

Comment: Is possible to start a webdriver with auto-launch fakse just to change device language for instance, quit. Then start a new webdrive with my full capabilities?